# Increase load time in turn.js to load faster my flipbook

Tags: jquery, performance

I am using turn.js (3rd release) jquery to get flipbook effect in my website, i am using sequence of images as page to load using turn.js in flipbook.\

my question is, currently it take too much time to load flipbook in my site, because turn.js first loading all the images and then start animating, i want to load first 4 or 6 images and then start animating and while user read 1-6th page the all other pages are loaded dynamically in the chunks.

is it possible ?

Any help appreciated

Comment: I've never used turn.js but judging from the API you may try to use the [pages option](http://www.turnjs.com/docs/Option:_pages), the [pages method](http://www.turnjs.com/docs/Method:_pages) and the [addPage method](http://www.turnjs.com/docs/Method:_addPage) to add dynamically new pages. There's also a [page property](http://www.turnjs.com/docs/Property:_page) to figure out the current page.

Comment: Thank you Geeo,                                                                    but i am new to jquery and don't know enough to code in jquery